# After user authentication from Azure AD, all claims(group details) are not coming, happening for some users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, authorization

I have .Net web application hosted in App Service in Azure. User is getting authenticated with the help of Azure AD. Application is redirecting to login page and after authentication. But, after coming back to the application(after authentication), all claim details(group id's/details) of login user are not coming, causing the authorization issue(with the help of group id/details, we are authorizing the user to access the particular page)

Here the problem is, for some users all group details are coming and they are accessing the required page. Where as for some other users, even if user is authorized member(say admin group member), still he is not able to see the page because of claims/group details are not coming.  Why it is happening and what is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are limitations for the token size, which causes those claims to be left out in some cases.
If you are using implicit grant, the limits are quite strict.
But even in authorization code grant, there is a limit of 200 group ids.

If this limit is breached, no ids are sent.
Since that might hide the issue :)

A solution is to query the user group memberships etc. from Graph API when this occurs.
You can detect this by looking for the "hasgroups" claim.
At the moment you cannot decide which groups should be sent in tokens.
If in the future we get an option to only send ids of groups which are assigned to this app etc., that would help this use case a lot.

See the docs for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims

Comment: What you said is correct. Users who are member of 200+ azure ad groups, they are not getting the group details. Rather they are receiving a url to retrieve the groups. So now, I need query the user groups for the logged in user. I need to do in c# code. How can I retrieve the user groups for logged in user? Do I need to use Graph API or Azure AD Graph api. Which one to choose. Any sample code helps me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Microsoft Graph API definitely. You can use for example this endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. I recommend you use the Microsoft.Graph package from Nuget :)

Comment: Thank you @juunas.
 Under App regiration of Azure AD, for my client application under api permissions blade, we provided "Microsoft Graph api" with Application Permissions for Group Members Reading.
With this now I can make the request to Graph Api from my c# client application, but to make the request with Graph api do I need token? It's saying that "without user context" can access the api.  

What exactly difference between delegate permissions and application permissions. Do we need token for both of them?

Comment: Yes those tokens are different. Application permissions only apply when you get a token with only application credentials. Delegated permissions only apply when you get a token for a signed-in user, for example through authorization code flow.